# Post Date to WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've got a webAPI controller that accepts a Profile Object

```
public IHttpActionResult CreateProfile([FromBody] Profile request)
```

The Profile Object has a `DateTime` attribute on it. I am creating a Profile Object in my Client Side app (Xamarin.Forms) and posting that to the WebAPI. However the Date doesn't get picked up by WebAPI.

What format does the date need to be sent to WebAPI in?

**EDIT**

Simplified Client Code:

```
var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("DateOfBirth", date_of_birth.Date.ToUniversalTime().ToString())
});
await Update(formContent);
```

```
public async Task<string>Update(FormUrlEncodedContent profileUpdates)
{
  var client = new HttpClient();
  client.BaseAddress = new Uri(server_url);
  var method = new HttpMethod("POST");
  var method_url = server_url + "/api/UpdateProfile";
  var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, method_url);
  request.Content = profileUpdates;
  var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

  if (response.StatusCode==HttpStatusCode.OK)
  {
    return "Profile Updated";
  }
}
```

Simplified Server Model

```
public class Profile
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: is the date null or the whole `request` or what does "doesn't get picked up" mean? Could you also add the code from the client, where you send your POST request?

Comment: Dates should be sent in the "[roundtrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip)" format (`dateTime.ToString("o")`). See [How to: Round-trip Date and Time Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-round-trip-date-and-time-values).

Comment: Please share Profile model and posted JSON

Comment: You need to add the `O` format specifier so that the DateTime is sent in [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format (aka [round trip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-round-trip-date-and-time-values)). `date_of_birth.Date.ToUniversalTime().ToString("O")`. This ensures that the locale of the client does not send the DateTime in an ambigious format (*like `05-06-2017` as that could mean may 6th or june 5th*). Does that solve the issue?

Comment: *If the above does not work*: Does it work for `Name` if you add that to the existing `formContent` (do not remove `DateOfBirth`) ?